# pip3 Error "The 'pip==18.0' distribution was not found and is required by the application"

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, pip, ubuntu-18.04

on ubunut 18.04 Im trying to use `pip3` to install a package but when I try I get this Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip3", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3126, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3110, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3139, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 583, in _build_master
    return cls._build_from_requirements(__requires__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 596, in _build_from_requirements
    dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 784, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pip==18.0' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

OS details:

```
$ uname -srpo 
Linux 4.15.0-42-generic x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

How can I Fix this?